# Consistently high disk usage slowing down computer

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, performance, vmware-workstation

I am getting extremely high disk usage on my computer when running my virtual machine which is causing the vm to slow to a crawl. The native OS is Windows 8.1. The vm is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit running in vmware workstation. My drive has 409 GB free out of ~650, 8GB RAM, and quad core i7 processor. I dedicated 4 GB RAM, 75 GB HDD, and 2 processors (2 cores per processor) to the vm. Does anyone know why I might be getting this high disk usage. Hard drive is not SSD. I check the performance panel in Windows task manager and Memory (RAM) is at 5.3 / 8 GB with vm powered up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High disk usage is typically caused by many processes making requests for data stored on the disk.

In the "Performance" tab of Task Manager, click on "Resource Monitor" and expand the section labelled "Disk". You will be able to see which processes are using the disk.