# 100% Disk usage and frequent lags, what to do?

Tags: lag

My laptop has become real slow very fast for short tasks. I can't open anything else while using Chrome. I have 8GB DDR4-2400 RAM and an i5 6th Generation CPU. My Task Manager shows 100% data usage, and 70% RAM usage while doing something. I have my disk health in CrystalDiskInfo and it shows it's in good condition. I've checked for bad sectors and I've found none, and I've done defragmentation, thinking there's a problem with my HDD.

What should I do about it?

Would adding another 8GB of RAM help, or changing my HDD?

Also, I have dual boot laptop, is this the issue that causes all this?

[ScreenShot of Task Manager with only Chrome Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh7yB.png)

[Screenshot of Task Manager just after Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cQOr.jpg)

> Edit: I reset my windows and still the disk usage is 100%, but before i did tweaks provided in previous answers which reduced disk usages but still lags persist.
>   Windows Version: Windows 10 Single Home 1809

Comment: What are the "short" tasks? Do you have a HDD or SSD?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your Task Manager, with the items sorted by CPU use?

Comment: Can you also argue how your situation is different than other posts on Super User? In the current state it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Joachim You should post a link to the duplicate.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/932755/consistently-high-disk-usage-slowing-down-computer), [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1184250/windows-abnormally-high-disk-usage-100-disk-usage), or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1099164/high-disk-usage-on-windows-10), to name a few, seem to be competitors at this point.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch hard disk, short tasks like usual things, browser, video player and something else..

Comment: @Joachim The answers in there tell how to watch for things that create a problem, all that disk checking are done from my side and no good solution was yielded.

Comment: What Windows version are you using?

Comment: Sounds like process monitor is needed... Could be an old hard drive, anti virus background task... Too many to name. Google process monitor and see if that sheds anything. Also, if applicable, run a SMART scan